# Consequences of $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective in the following sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, exact-sequence

I am trying to study if there can be a SES of the following form

$$0 \to \mathbb Z_4 \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2 \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb Z_4 \to 0.$$

So, I know if there is one, $f$ must be injective and $g$ must be surjective. I do not understand why $f$ is injective, this will leads that $\mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb Z _4$ could someone explain this to me please?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Some context might be helpful.  Do you know what a short exact sequence is?  Do you know what $f$ and $g$ are?

Comment: This is not a short exact sequence by given. No, $f$ and $g$ are just the shown functions, no information about their definitions, just knowing their domains and codomains.@lulu Actually, I am studying if there can exist a SES like this.

Comment: You should edit your post to reflect that...as written, people will assume it is intended to be exact.   Presumably $f$ maps to the cyclic subgroup of order $4$ in $\mathbb Z_8$, but then $g$ does not work.

Comment: Also, if $f$ is injective, does that means $$\mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$$ contains an isomorphic copy of  $\mathbb Z_4$? if so, why?

Comment: @lulu ok, I will edit my question.

Comment: If $F:H\to G$ is injective then $F(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$, isomorphic to $H$.

Comment: Oh , I see $f$ is an isomorphism on its image @lulu got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exact sequence is a sequence of morphisms such that the image of one morphism is equal to the kernel of the next. If this sequence is exact (**this is never said, but this is the most important part**) then:

- the first map from $0$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is injective since the domain has only one element, and its image is only one element, the $0$ of $\mathbb{Z}_4$.
- The image of $0\to \mathbb{Z}_4$ is equal to the kernel of $f$, so $f$ is injective.

Similarly for the second part of the sequence

- The codomain of the last map is a single element $0$, and so the kernel of the last map is the whole group $\mathbb{Z}_4$.
- Because the image of $g$ is equal to the kernel of the last map, $g$ must be surjective.

All of this follows from the sequence being an **exact** sequence.
This creates strong constraints on the functions $f$ and $g$, and in general, is not true.

The moral of the story is that, in an exact sequence, writing $0\to A \xrightarrow{f} B$ is a way to say $f$ is injective, and $A \xrightarrow{g} B\to 0$ is a way to say $g$ is surjective.

Comment: I think in your first bullet, it should be injective instead, am I correct?

Comment: But you still did not answer my question I asked, why there is an **isomorphic **copy of $\mathbb Z_4$? $f$ is injective and not isomorphism.

Comment: @Brain It was not clear at all that THAT was your question. $f: \mathbb Z_4 \rightarrow \mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$ is not an isomorphism, but $f: \mathbb Z_4 \rightarrow \text{Im}(f)$ is.

Comment: @Brain 1) It should be injective, I have corrected it

2) $f$ is injective, so the domain is isomorphic to the image. More precisely, from the first isomorphism theorem we have $\operatorname{Domain}(f)/\operatorname{Ker}(f) \cong \operatorname{Im}(f)$. In this particular case $\operatorname{Ker}(f)=\{0\}$, so we have an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By the isomorphism theorem applied to $g$, we would have
$$
\left(\mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\right)\ /\ \mathrm{Im}(f) \cong 
\mathbb Z_4,
$$
since $\mathrm{ker}\ g=\mathrm{Im}\ f$. Now go through the few choices for $f$, and see what you find. Note that $f$ is determined by the image of a generator of $\mathbb Z_4$, and this image must have order $4$ in $\mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$, so there are only a few possibilities.

Comment: I know what is the image of $f(1)$ it is either $(\pm 2,1)$ or $(\pm 2,0)$ but then I want to apply $g$ to those elements and conclude that they are equal to the kernel of g, but I do not know how

Comment: How can I know the values of $g$ on $(1,0)$ and (0,1), could you please clarify this to me?

Comment: I wouldn’t focus on $g$ as such, but rather study the quotient group I wrote. The SES exists iff the quotient is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$ for some choice of $f$. More concretely: find all subgroups of $\Bbb Z_8\oplus\Bbb Z_2$ that are isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$; these are the choices of the image of $f$. For each of them, determine if the quotient group has an element of order $4$ or not.

Comment: The only two subgroups of $\mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$ which are isomorphic to $ \mathbb Z_4$ are:

$\langle(\bar{2}, \bar{0})\rangle = \{(\bar{0}, \bar{0}),(\bar{2}, \bar{0}),(\bar{4}, \bar{0}),(\bar{6}, \bar{0})\}$ and $\langle(\bar{2}, \bar{1})\rangle = \{(\bar{0}, \bar{0}),(\bar{2}, \bar{1}),(\bar{4}, \bar{0}),(\bar{6}, \bar{1})\}.$

Comment: Can you please show me the details of "For each of them, determine if the quotient group has an element of order 4 or not" on one of the subgroups I mentioned above?